# execute + colon character doesn't work

Tags: vimrc, normal-mode, functions, command

I want to `:retab` selection in my vimscript function.

When I write `execute "normal! :'<,'>retab"` nothing happens.

If I write:

```
let cmd = "normal! :'<,'>retab"
echom cmd
```

The output is what I would expect:
`normal! :<a:firstline>,<a:lastline>retab`

If I do this however...

```
let cmd = "normal! :'<,'>retab"
echom cmd
execute cmd
```

The output is empty...

I eventually used the `feedkeys` function, to simulate what I wanted to achieve. Just for the completion sake, it's `call feedkeys(":'<,'>retab\<CR>", 'n')`.

I narrowed the problem down to the fact, that `:` character is in the command, but it's quite weird... Is this prohibited in vimscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a final `<CR>` at the end of your `normal` command. If at the end of `normal` you have an incomplete command, it will cancel it as if `<Esc>` or `<C-c>` was pressed.

So this should fix it:

```
execute "normal! :'<,'>retab\<CR>"
```

(Using `\r` inside the double quotes is also possible.)

But in this case, there's probably no need to use `normal` or `execute`, since `retab` itself is already an Ex command, so you can simply use this directly:

```
'<,'>retab
```

That's a perfectly valid command in Vimscript.